# Are there any "hidden" abilities for classes other then the paladin?

Tags: rogue-legacy

When i was playing Paladin i found out by accident that if you press **`down`** and then button for **`special ability`** you will turn into a statue that wont take any damage from enemies. Now that wasn't mentioned in the upgrade description for this class, nor did i see it mentioned anywhere else in the game.

Do any other classes have this kind of "hidden" abilities?

Comment: This is something separate from the Paladin's regular damage prevention?

Comment: @Fluttershy Well Paladin's regular damage prevention is to put his shield up and block all incoming damage for 25 MP per hit, right? If you press down+A then he literally turns into a statue that can't be damaged but it keeps draining mana as long as you're in statue form.

Comment: Haven't played this game yet, but is this possibly just a Mario reference that's a one-of?

Comment: @Shinrai Sounds more like a Kirby reference to me

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - I was thikning specifically in terms of "Press down + button, turn into invincible statue" - isn't that how the tanooki suit did it in SMB3?  (I haven't actually played it in probably 15 years so I may be remembering incorrectly)

Comment: @Shinrai: I was thinking Down+B as Kirby in Smash Bros. *(or just `B` in Kirby games)*.  It turns out you were right though; the source-code internally refers to this ability as 'tanooki'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I looked through the code hoping to find any more special abilities, but didn't see any.

All the code for handling input, including special abilities, is in `RogueCastle.PlayerObj.InputControls()`.  It's rather large, but the part that controls the special abilities is short and straightforward.  Pressing 'block' while holding 'down' as the Paladin calls `RogueCastle.PlayerObj.ActivateTanooki()` *(or, if you're already a tanooki, `RogueCastle.PlayerObj.DeactivateTanooki()`)*; however, there is nothing unexpected for any of the other classes.

I looked through the rest of `InputControls()` to see if I could find anything out of the ordinary, but everything was normal.  That of course doesn't mean there aren't any *other* secrets in the game, but it's a pretty strong indication that there are no other secret special abilities.

---

As a bonus, here are all the possible states the player can be in:

```
public const int STATE_IDLE = 0;
public const int STATE_WALKING = 1;
public const int STATE_JUMPING = 2;
public const int STATE_HURT = 3;
public const int STATE_DASHING = 4;
public const int STATE_LEVELUP = 5;
public const int STATE_BLOCKING = 6;
public const int STATE_FLYING = 7;
public const int STATE_TANOOKI = 8;
public const int STATE_DRAGON = 9;
```

Answer (score -1):

Paladin is the only class with a hidden ability at this time.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?